# Filter DataFrame using Series.str.match()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use str.match() and i did use this function with my data. and its working very well. But I have a question, I want to save the rest of the data in another DataFrame, and then save it to_csv().

Any Idea about that. Thanks in advance.

```
Address = df[df['Address'].str.match('nan')]
Address = pd.DataFrame(Address)
Address.to_csv(r'nan_Address_df.csv',index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest create new variable `mask`, filter for `Address` matched rows and for `Address1` non matched rows with inverted mask by `~`:

```
mask = df['Address'].str.match('nan')
#alternative
#mask = df['Address'].str.contains('nan')
Address = df[mask]

Address1 = df[~mask]
```